# spring cloud gateway global exception handling/logging

Tags: spring, logging, error-handling, spring-webflux, spring-cloud-gateway

I have a spring cloud gateway application that acts as a gateway for my dataservice. My application uses SSE to push notifications in the UI. When I see the log of my gateway, I have my log filled with exceptions like:

```
 2019-01-25 07:39:13,807 ERROR [reactor-http-nio-3] org.springframework.web.server.adapter.HttpWebHandlerAdapter : Unhandled failure: Connection reset by peer, response
already set (status=200)
2019-01-25 07:39:13,809 ERROR [reactor-http-nio-3] org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ReactorHttpHandlerAdapter : Handling completed with error
java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
        at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:47) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:51) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:471) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
        at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doWrite(NioSocketChannel.java:403) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar!/:4.1.22.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.flush0(AbstractChannel.java:934) [netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar!/:4.1.22.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.flush0(AbstractNioChannel.java:360) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar!/:4.1.22.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.flush(AbstractChannel.java:901) [netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar!/:4.1.22.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.flush(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1376) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar!/:4.1.22.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:776) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar!/:4.1.22.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:768) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar!/:4.1.22.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.flush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:749) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar!/:4.1.22.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.forceFlush(SslHandler.java:1746) ~[netty-handler-4.1.22.Final.jar!/:4.1.22.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.wrapAndFlush(SslHandler.java:757) ~[netty-handler-4.1.22.Final.jar!/:4.1.22.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.flush(SslHandler.java:734) ~[netty-handler-4.1.22.Final.jar!/:4.1.22.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:776) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar!/:4.1.22.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:768) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar!/:4.1.22.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.flush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:749) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar!/:4.1.22.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.flush(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:533) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar!/:4.1.22.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter.flush(ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter.java:115) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar!/:4.1.22.Final]

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

2019-01-25 07:40:37,432 ERROR [reactor-http-nio-1] reactor.ipc.netty.channel.CloseableContextHandler : Handler failure while no child channelOperation was present
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: handshake timed out
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.handshake(...)(Unknown Source) ~[netty-handler-4.1.22.Final.jar!/:4.1.22.Final]
2019-01-25 07:40:39,512 ERROR [reactor-http-nio-3] org.springframework.web.server.adapter.HttpWebHandlerAdapter : Unhandled failure: Connection reset by peer, response
already set (status=200)
2019-01-25 07:40:39,513 ERROR [reactor-http-nio-3] org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ReactorHttpHandlerAdapter : Handling completed with error
java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
        at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:47) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:51) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:471) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
        at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doWrite(NioSocketChannel.java:403) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar!/:4.1.22.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.flush0(AbstractChannel.java:934) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar!/:4.1.22.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.flush0(AbstractNioChannel.java:360) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar!/:4.1.22.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.flush(AbstractChannel.java:901) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar!/:4.1.22.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.flush(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1376) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar!/:4.1.22.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:776) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar!/:4.1.22.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:768) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar!/:4.1.22.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.flush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:749) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar!/:4.1.22.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.forceFlush(SslHandler.java:1746) ~[netty-handler-4.1.22.Final.jar!/:4.1.22.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.wrapAndFlush(SslHandler.java:757) ~[netty-handler-4.1.22.Final.jar!/:4.1.22.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.flush(SslHandler.java:734) ~[netty-handler-4.1.22.Final.jar!/:4.1.22.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:776) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar!/:4.1.22.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:768) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar!/:4.1.22.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.flush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:749) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar!/:4.1.22.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.flush(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:533) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar
!/:4.1.22.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter.flush(ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter.java:115) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar!/:4.1.22.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.flush(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:358) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar!/:4.1.22.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:776) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar!/:4.1.22.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:768) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar!/:4.1.22.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.flush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:749) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar!/:4.1.22.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.ChannelDuplexHandler.flush(ChannelDuplexHandler.java:117) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar!/:4.1.22.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:776) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar!/:4.1.22.Final]

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


2019-01-25 07:43:47,048 ERROR [reactor-http-nio-3] org.springframework.web.server.adapter.HttpWebHandlerAdapter : Unhandled failure: Connection reset by peer, response
already set (status=200)
2019-01-25 07:43:47,049 ERROR [reactor-http-nio-3] org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ReactorHttpHandlerAdapter : Handling completed with error
java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
        at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:47) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:51) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:471) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
        at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doWrite(NioSocketChannel.java:403) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar!/:4.1.22.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.flush0(AbstractChannel.java:934) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar!/:4.1.22.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.flush0(AbstractNioChannel.java:360) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar!/:4.1.22.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.flush(AbstractChannel.java:901) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar!/:4.1.22.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.flush(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1376) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar!/:4.1.22.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:776) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar!/:4.1.22.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:768) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar!/:4.1.22.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.flush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:749) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar!/:4.1.22.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.forceFlush(SslHandler.java:1746) ~[netty-handler-4.1.22.Final.jar!/:4.1.22.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.wrapAndFlush(SslHandler.java:757) ~[netty-handler-4.1.22.Final.jar!/:4.1.22.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.flush(SslHandler.java:734) ~[netty-handler-4.1.22.Final.jar!/:4.1.22.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:776) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar!/:4.1.22.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:768) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar!/:4.1.22.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.flush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:749) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar!/:4.1.22.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.flush(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:533) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar
!/:4.1.22.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter.flush(ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter.java:115) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar!/:4.1.22.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.flush(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:358) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar!/:4.1.22.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:776) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar!/:4.1.22.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:768) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar!/:4.1.22.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.flush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:749) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar!/:4.1.22.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.ChannelDuplexHandler.flush(ChannelDuplexHandler.java:117) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar!/:4.1.22.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:776) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar!/:4.1.22.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:768) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar!/:4.1.22.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.flush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:749) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar!/:4.1.22.Final]
        at reactor.ipc.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.doWrite(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:296) ~[reactor-netty-0.7.5.RELEASE.jar!/:0.7.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.ipc.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.drain(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:465) ~[reactor-netty-0.7.5.RELEASE.jar!/:0.7.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.ipc.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.flush(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:191) ~[reactor-netty-0.7.5.RELEASE.jar!/:0.7.5.RELEASE]
```

I have an error handler class:

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.server.ServerWebExchange;
import org.springframework.web.server.WebExceptionHandler;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

import java.io.IOException;

@Component
public class GlobalExceptionHandler implements WebExceptionHandler {

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> handle(ServerWebExchange exchange, Throwable exception) {
        if (exchange.getResponse().isCommitted()) {
            //for SSE connections, privents from filling up logs when connection is closed.
            if(exception instanceof IOException && (exception.getMessage().contains("An established connection was aborted") || exception.getMessage().contains("Connection closed prematurely"))){
                return exchange.getResponse().writeWith(Flux.just());
            }
        }
        return Mono.error(exception);
    }
}
```

but it is still logging the error. How do I make my gateway not write the logs.

My pom file is:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>microservices-api-gateway</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>api-gateway</name>
    <description>description</description>

    <parent>
        <artifactId>project-parent-pom</artifactId>
        <groupId>xxx.xx</groupId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencyManagement>

        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>

            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-gateway-core
            Due to defect in previous version higher version of cloud gateway was used-->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-gateway-core</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <spring-cloud.version>Finchley.RELEASE</spring-cloud.version>
        <env.properties>config/${environment}_env.properties</env.properties>
        <resources.version>3.0.2</resources.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>-->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-starter-hystrix -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

My dependency Tree:

```
 com.vh:microservices-api-gateway:jar:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-gateway:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-context:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-crypto:jar:5.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-commons:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-rsa:jar:1.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-gateway-core:jar:2.0.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- io.projectreactor.addons:reactor-extra:jar:3.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- io.projectreactor:reactor-core:jar:3.1.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:jar:2.9.4:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.9.4:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:jar:2.9.4:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-reactor-netty:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- io.projectreactor.ipc:reactor-netty:jar:0.7.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     |     +- io.netty:netty-codec-http:jar:4.1.22.Final:compile
[INFO] |     |     |  \- io.netty:netty-codec:jar:4.1.22.Final:compile
[INFO] |     |     +- io.netty:netty-handler:jar:4.1.22.Final:compile
[INFO] |     |     |  +- io.netty:netty-buffer:jar:4.1.22.Final:compile
[INFO] |     |     |  \- io.netty:netty-transport:jar:4.1.22.Final:compile
[INFO] |     |     |     \- io.netty:netty-resolver:jar:4.1.22.Final:compile
[INFO] |     |     +- io.netty:netty-handler-proxy:jar:4.1.22.Final:compile
[INFO] |     |     |  \- io.netty:netty-codec-socks:jar:4.1.22.Final:compile
[INFO] |     |     \- io.netty:netty-transport-native-epoll:jar:4.1.22.Final:compile
[INFO] |     |        +- io.netty:netty-common:jar:4.1.22.Final:compile
[INFO] |     |        \- io.netty:netty-transport-native-unix-common:jar:4.1.22.Final:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:jar:6.0.7.Final:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:2.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.2.Final:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.3.4:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework:spring-webflux:jar:5.0.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.synchronoss.cloud:nio-multipart-parser:jar:1.1.0:compile
[INFO] |        \- org.synchronoss.cloud:nio-stream-storage:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.19:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.0.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.0.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:5.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:5.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.0.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:5.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.0.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-netflix-core:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-netflix-ribbon:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-netflix-archaius:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-archaius:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.netflix.archaius:archaius-core:jar:0.7.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:3.0.1:runtime
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-configuration:commons-configuration:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.netflix.hystrix:hystrix-core:jar:1.5.12:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.reactivex:rxjava:jar:1.3.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.hdrhistogram:HdrHistogram:jar:2.1.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.netflix.hystrix:hystrix-serialization:jar:1.5.12:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-afterburner:jar:2.9.4:runtime
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.9.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.netflix.hystrix:hystrix-metrics-event-stream:jar:1.5.12:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.netflix.hystrix:hystrix-javanica:jar:1.5.12:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.7:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.4:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.8.13:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.google.guava:guava:jar:15.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- io.reactivex:rxjava-reactive-streams:jar:1.2.1:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:jar:1.0.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security.oauth.boot:spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.9.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.9.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2:jar:2.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:5.0.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.11:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-jwt:jar:1.0.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:jar:1.56:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:jar:1.56:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.0.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:test
[INFO]    +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:test
[INFO]    +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:test
[INFO]    +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.4.0:test
[INFO]    |  \- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.3:test
[INFO]    |     \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:1.2:test
[INFO]    +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
[INFO]    +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:3.9.1:test
[INFO]    +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:2.15.0:test
[INFO]    |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.7.10:test
[INFO]    |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:jar:1.7.10:test
[INFO]    |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.6:test
[INFO]    +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO]    +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:jar:1.3:test
[INFO]    +- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.5.0:test
[INFO]    |  \- com.vaadin.external.google:android-json:jar:0.0.20131108.vaadin1:test
[INFO]    +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.0.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.0.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:5.0.4.RELEASE:test
[INFO]    \- org.xmlunit:xmlunit-core:jar:2.5.1:test
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error doesn't happen during the handling phase, but during the actual streaming of the response. This is quite low-level and is not covered by the `WebExceptionHandler` contract.

It looks like you're using Spring Framework 5.0.x, and in this version this exception is logged at WARN level, [as of 5.0.6 and #21229](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/21229). In Spring Framework 5.1.x, [significant changes have been made to the logging experience](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/21437), and those logs are now at the TRACE level, so you shouldn't see those by default anymore.

In the meantime, you can adapt the logging level for the `ReactorHttpHandlerAdapter` class and only consider ERROR level logs.

Comment: My spring framework version is org.springframework:spring-core:5.1.2.RELEASE. The above mentioned errors are at ERROR level, how would adapting log levels for ReactorHttpHandlerAdapter help?

Comment: Are you sure about that? The commit history tells me that the log statement "Handling completed with error" was changed in 5.1. It was also at the WARN level. Please update your question with a pom.xml/build.gradle (and a dependency tree output), as well as a log output with more context to it (we're missing other statements around as well as the log level)

Comment: I have updated my question with few error log stack and my pom file

Comment: oh sorry. my spring framework version is actually org.springframework:spring-core:5.0.4.RELEASE. My Ide was not updating imports. But adapting log levels would still not help right?

Comment: Indeed it won't help with Spring Framework 5.0.4, since the log level has been changed in 5.0.6 to warn in https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/21229. Looking at the compatibility between Spring Cloud and Spring Boot, maybe you can update the Spring Boot version? 2.0.2.RELEASE and later is using WARN as level.

Comment: Sure. Thanks for the direction.

Comment: I updated the version to 2.0.2.RELEASE and I dont see the logs anymore. However, I am looking into the memory usage of the application now and its almost 2-3 times (From 400MB to 1GB now). Is there any reason to explain this behaviour?

Comment: Not on the top of my head. Did you profile it to see what's that extra memory is being used for?